# Símbolo ; no Lua

Tags: lua

Como funciona o símbolo `;` no Lua?

```
;;;;
; ;

do ; end;
do ;end
do ;end;
do;end;
;do end
;do end;
;do ; end;
;;do ; end

do end
```

Comment: Acho interessante demais a iniciativa de perguntar a responder. Eu sou mestre em fazer isso aqui. Mas creio que, quando for fazer, tanto pergunta como resposta devem estar claro, para não dar a impressão que só você sabe responder aquilo que perguntou. E editar a pergunta será uma ótima oportunidade para outros usuários colocaram algo a mais como resposta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Sim, é isso que estou fazendo. Como estou fazendo isso no mobile, meus edits estão sendo meio lentos, ainda tentarei ser mais claro se possível.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters A resposta foi editada de acordo com o novo edit na pergunta. Agora vou arranjar um jeito de clarificar isso no celular.

Comment: Perfeito! Eu também estava usando o mobile hoje (um saco pra editar/escrever)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Acho que dá p/ re-abrir a pergunta

Answer (score 6):

*Obs.: *statement* é uma instrução não expressiva.*

Basicamente semicolons (os símbolos `;`) separam statements, mas na versão 5.2 há uma simples mudança.

**Velho funcionamento**

Até a versão 5.1, os semicolons [separam statements](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#2.4.1), podendo aparecer apenas depois do fim opcional de um statement. Não necessariamente que semicolons separam statements.

**Novo funcionamento**

Na versão 5.2 semicolons geram, ou em outras palavras, se tornam [*empty* statements](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.1), statements que não fazem nada. É inespecífico se os empty statements delimitam statements, mas eles podem ser ignorados (não "listados") por interpretadores. No Lua não existe, por exemplo, `for (;;) ;` no ECMAScript, onde o empty statement seria o corpo desse loop nativo, então o interpretador do Lua simplesmente ignora os empty statements (não "lista" eles), é possível ver isso no código fonte da linguagem.

Isso é perfeitamente válido na versão 5.2+:

```
; chamada();;;;
```

---

Aqui fica um exemplo de como as versões se diferenciam.

Isso é sempre válido:

```
do end;
```

mas

```
do
    ;
end
```

,

```
; do end
```

ou

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;; do ;;;;; end ;;;;;;
```

são incorretos nas versões abaixo de 5.2, pois um ou mais semicolons não aparecem depois de um statement.